# Python/NumPy: Return a List of Smaller (LHS) + Larger Elements (RHS) out of the Two Lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Hie all, I would like to do something simple, which is comparing `A` and `B` then return the smaller element on the left hand column (column 0) and the larger element on the right hand column (column 1).

Say,

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[  311.,360.],
             [-4022.,-3973.],
             [   96.,145.],
             [ 3989.,4038.]])
```

and,

```
B = np.array([[310.,460.],
             [ -4018.,4013.],
             [ -297.,-256.],
             [ 4005.,4039.]])
```

I would like to get:-

```
C = [[  310.,460.],
     [-4022.,4013.],
     [  -297.,145.],
     [ 3989.,4039.]]
```

I tried `A[A>B]` but the positions of the elements are not in order. Is there a sleek way to solve this? Thank you for your attention and kind help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `A[A>B]` you get a list of all elements of `A` which are larger than the corresponding elements of `B`.
Use instead

```
>>> idx1 = A[:,0]<B[:,0]
>>> idx2 = A[:,1]>B[:,1]
>>> idx = np.column_stack((idx1,idx2))
>>> np.where(idx,A,B)
array([[  310.,   460.],
       [-4022.,  4013.],
       [ -297.,   145.],
       [ 3989.,  4039.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a simpler way to do this, but this works fine:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[  311.,360.],
             [-4022.,-3973.],
             [   96.,145.],
             [ 3989.,4038.]])

B = np.array([[310.,460.],
             [ -4018.,4013.],
             [ -297.,-256.],
             [ 4005.,4039.]])
#join the desired columns
firstcol = np.vstack((A[:,0], B[:,0]))
secondcol = np.vstack((A[:,1], B[:,1]))

#find the min and max values
mincol =  np.amin(firstcol, axis=0)
maxcol = np.amax(secondcol, axis=0)

C = np.vstack((mincol, maxcol))
print C.T
[[  310.   460.]
 [-4022.  4013.]
 [ -297.   145.]
 [ 3989.  4039.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending from @plonser's answer, a one-line solution I implemented is:

```
C = np.array([np.where(A<B,A,B)[:,0],
              np.where(A>B,A,B)[:,1]]).T
```

Thank you all for helping out!